# How to find best fit for one polynomial to another by shifting x

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, least-squares

I have two polynomials:

$y_1 = .00006x^2 + .0014x + 59.47$

$y_2 = .00006x^2 + .0012x + 59.463$

[image: Plot]

I need to figure out how much to shift $x$ in $y_2$ so that it has the best fit with $y_1$.

Note: these are not the same curve with one simply shifted horizontally so there is no way to fit them perfectly by shifting x, I just need a best fit.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a least squares regression, but am having trouble figuring out how exactly to put that together for this problem. All of the information I can find through Google is related to finding line of best fit for a data set or lining up two curves using software (with no explanation of the math, which is what I need).

Let me know if anything is unclear or if I need to provide more detail - I think I covered everything and expressed my question as clearly as I can, but can certainly try to improve it if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "fit"? Supremum norm, L2, L1 distance over some segment, minimum distance between the minima of these two functions, something else? You could have an explicit or approximate answer depending on what you are looking for

Comment: If you wrote $ax_2 + bx_1 + cx_0$ instead of $ax^2 + bx + c$ could you solve it as a linear regression problem?

Comment: @CyclotomicField That seems like a good push in the right direction and I'll let you know if I was able to figure this problem out using that suggestion once I finally figure out how to do the calculations for a linear regression.

Comment: @charmd I wish I had a more technical meaning of "fit", but to do my best to explain it in plain English, I need to shift y2 horizontally until it most closely lines up with y1 over the range of x=0 to whatever the highest x-value in the data set is. A least squares regression seems to make sense as a way to find this, but I'm only familiar with how to do that for finding a line of best fit for a set of data, not for aligning two different curves. I suspect that CyclotomicField's reply is a hint in the right direction, but my math is so rusty I haven't figured out how to use it yet.